# Handling XML loaded from a webservice on iphone app startup

Tags: iphone, xml, sqlite

We are creating an application that interfaces with our current system which uses a web service to retrieve the current XML file for that user.

The XML file needs to be updated each time the application starts up, unless no internet connection is available, in which case the application needs to use the base XML file within the app bundle to populate certain fields.

The application is currently taking a long time to retrieve and process the XML document, or decide to use the base XML.  As this is a project for work, I am not allowed to post the code for viewing.

The XML document is then written to a sqlite DB which is utilized by the application. This entire process must be completed prior to the user being able to do anything in the application.

The question is, is there a way to speed up this process with the current format... the current format is a web service outputs XML the requested files from an SQLServer DB. Is it better to build a new web service that outputs some other type of file that is quicker to use within the app?

Comment: If you can't show exact code, you should at least show us a simplified version, otherwise we can't give any suggestions on speeding it up.

Answer (score 0):

so your app is slow due to large amount of data storage. Currently I am also working on similar project in which I have to do similar kind of things.
 Now what I found was that due to large amount of data which is to be retrieved from the server must be not done in main thread. That is what taking your time.
 So the solution is to do all retrieve on another Queue/Thread. You can dispatch all of your backend data to that queue. While after some of your data is saved you can start showing to user in main queue. Meanwhile, the different queue used will save all of your data to the database. So its like saving and viewing parts of data.
 You can read on GCD/Threads on developers site/other tutorials for its implementation.